# Rails: trying to store particular column value in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am building an application in rails, and I have an items_controller which contains the methods application for create, show, edit, destroy etc.

However, I am trying to create my own method to access all the values in a specific column of my database and I am having greatly difficulty in capturing this data in an array.

I have tried the following ways of capturing the data (where 'quantity' is the column in the database for which I looking for):

```
@items = Item.find(params[:id])
@items2 = @item.find(params[:quantity])
```

I have also tried:

```
@items = Item.find(params[:quantity])
```

& even:

```
 @items = Item.all
 @items2 = @item.find(params[:quantity])
```

However, none of these methods appear to be working. For what I am doing it is not even essential to
know which quantity column values relate to which row...just getting a list of the column values would suffice.

If any one knows what is wrong here, the help you be very greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

For clarity I am trying to retrieve all the data for a particular column in my database associated with the items_controller and filter the data for a particular piece of data (in this case the string "7" - as the data is returned from the db as a string when using the Items.all method.

I then want a counter to increase each time the "7" is encountered in the quantity column.

```
def chartItems
  @items = Item.find(params[:id])
  @items2 = @items.find(params[:quantity])

  @filter = custom_filter_for(@items2)

def custom_filter_for(value)

   j=0               # counter initialised at 0

value.each do |x|        
  if x == "7"       # checking for data equal to "7" - the num is retrieved as a string
    j = j+1         # increase j counter by 1 whenever "7" is encountered as a quantity
  end
    return j
 end
end
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Show us the code for your `find` method.

Comment: if really need to get data of each raw for the specific column of the DB, you should get all record, and then enumarate it accessing the column: `records = Item.all` then `records.each {| row | row.column = value }` or etc.

Comment: Thanks a mil for the suggestion majioa much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `find` parameter is handled as an id in this case:

```
@items = Item.find(params[:quantity])
```

All items are returned which has the `id` of your `quantity` parameter. This is clearly not what you want.

You can select Items based on quantity:

```
@items = Item.find_by_quantity(params[:quantity])
```

But if you need only the quantities in an array, this is what you are looking for:

```
@quantities = Items.select(:quantity).map(&:quantity)
```

Your updated question:

```
result = Items.find_by_quantity(params[:quantity]).count
```

Answer (score 0):

In new versions of ActiveRecord, they've added the `pluck` which does essentially what @Matzi's `select` and `map` method does.

To get all item quantities, you could do

```
@quantities = Item.pluck(:quantity)
```

Also, I would double check your use of the `find_by` helpers.  I think that find_by_quantity will only give you a single match back (`@item`, not `@items`).  To get all, I think you really want to use `where`

```
@quantities = Item.where(:quantity => params[:quantity])
```

If you were to use the `pluck` I mentioned above, I think your filtering step could also be written pretty concisely.  That filter is simply counting the number of 7's in the list, right?

```
@quantities = Item.pluck(:quantity)
@filtered_values = @quantities.select{|q| q == 7}.length
```

I hope this helps out.